# What laws of physics suggest life and evolution will occur?

Tags: biophysics, biology, laws-of-physics

Do any laws of physics tell us why life and evolution occurs?

From my understanding the laws of physics is about reduction/materialism and with that we can explain everything else.

To that end, which laws suggest life will (1) arise and (2) evolve? Why don't the simplest organisms just pop in and out of existence without evolving?

Said differently, which underlying laws of physics predict the occurrence of life and evolution?

Comment: This might be too large a question to concisely answer on an SE, if only because many of the details of biology's emergence from physics are still not fully understood (let alone being attributable concisely to a few physical laws). But what's salient is the *statistics* of abiogenesis & natural selection. Your popping-in/out idea warrants an immediate "even they're too complex for that" response, but cf. [Boltzmann brains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain).

Comment: Physics is about understanding ***how*** the universe behaves. It is not about understanding ***why*** it behaves the way it does. Leave that to philosophers - they haven't made much progress in the past 3,000 years, but they might figure it out eventually!

Comment: Probably more a subject for [biology.se] although still probably too broad for the SE format to handle.

Comment: I think this a chemistry question, not physics or biology. ("How might self-replication with copy errors arise from chemical processes?") There's a bit of statistical mechanics to it, too. For a non-technical introduction, the first few chapters of "The Selfish Gene" by R. Dawkins has a good layman's treatment of the probable chemical origins of proto-organisms.

Comment: Physics can tell you why elementary chemical processes happen (they all boil down to "on average, systems tend towards their state of lowest local negentropy"), but it's a long, long road from first principals to even fairly simple chemistry.

Comment: It is the *maximum entropy production principle* you might be looking for, and its connection with cosmological and biological reproducibility, see this very readable chapter by Lineweaver.https://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~charley/papers/LineweaverChap_6.pdf

Comment: The 2nd law of thermodynamics seriously implies that spontaneous generation of some sort of life from inanimate substances is practically impossible.  In other words, you can't get an appropriate answer from physicists.

Comment: suggest as reference on this topic the book of Barrow and Tipler: *The cosmological anthropic principle*.

Comment: How about the explanation from Gell-Mann: "Everything not forbidden is compulsory."

Comment: You may want to look at this answer: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/101782/59521 I particularly recommend the Phil Anderson's article *More is different*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most evolutionary scientists assume that the origins of life and evolution are the result of random factors.  It was a random collection of chemicals in a random place on earth that led to the first life.  From then on, random events led to species dying off or evolving into higher forms.

If you look at [this site](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/evolution/library/faq/cat01.html) it says that The genetic variation on which natural selection acts may occur randomly, but natural selection itself is not random at all.  Thus we see that lots of random variation does indeed occur, and the vast majority of it simply fades away.  Only that random variation that actually benefits the species stays into the next generation.  But even the greatest evolutionary traits started with a random variation.

Randomness, or more particularly Quantum Randomness, plays a huge role in physics and has been studied to a great extent.  We can start with Schrodinger's Cat, "a hypothetical cat may be considered simultaneously both alive and dead as a result of its fate being linked to a random subatomic event that may or may not occur."  If we take this to a higher level, it is a quantum random event that leads to the formation of particular chemicals, that in turn became the first life.  And it is random events that lead to environmental changes that lead to evolution.  Take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02176) for full study of randomness in quantum physics, and how it leads to many other issues.

Regarding your thought on species popping in and out of existence, as I mentioned above the vast majority of random genetic variation simply fades away.  At a greater level, what was the cause of the asteroid collision that wiped out the dinosaurs?  Gravity and nothing else.  Clearly physics.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify how randomness in gene selection (which I would associate with classical statistical randomness in the same way that car accidents are random) is the same as quantum randomness, i.e. two states with identical initial conditions and evolutions can yield different outcomes after measurement.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  I guess you could say that every macro event starts with a micro event.  It is the random selection at the quantum level that leads to the formation of an atom, then a molecule, then a gene, then an evolutionary change.  It has often been asked why we can't make a perfect prediction of the future if we have complete information on the present.  The answer is because we can't predict these random changes.   As others have commented above, this is an esoteric question and we have to look at the overall picture to provide an answer.

Comment: The dominant random factors in play in the formation of molecules are not quantum, but thermodynamic: at what frequency does this bump into that, in such and such range of velocities, at such and such range of angles.